# SageMath version 9

Tags: python, python-3.x, sage

I have a script.py that worked until today, but today it gave an error, although when checking

```
sage -v
```

it says

```
SageMath version 9.0, Release Date: 2020-01-01
```

**using ubuntu 20.04**

on the first line is:

```
from sage.all import *
```

**error:**

```
sage-python3 script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/script.py", line 1, in <module>
     from sage.all import *
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/sage/all.py", line 77, in <module>
     from cysignals.signals import (AlarmInterrupt, SignalError,
   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cysignals/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
     from .signals import AlarmInterrupt, SignalError, init_cysignals # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cysignals.signals'sage-python3 script.py
```

Please tell me what is the reason for the error?

```
sage -python3 script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Sage can be built to use your system python (or it can be built to use its own python). This problem is caused because you updated system python packages, but didn't update sage.

I note that cysignals is itself maintained by the sage team. You can resolve this by updating/reinstalling/building sage.